# Anagram Dictionary As Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to create an anagram detector. Obviously the code below returns a syntax error as you cannot have a hashable type as a value or key.

#### Constraints: Cannot use imports.

```
>>> d1
{'star': {{'r': 1}, {'a': 1}, {'t': 1}, {'s': 1}} }

>>> d2
{'rats': {{'a': 1}, {'r': 1}, {'s': 1}, {'t': 1}} }
```

The reason why I am trying to store the letters counts as dict values is because I want to be able to take advantage of the `dict`'s built in `__eq__` check:

```
>>> d1['star'] == d2['rats']
True
```

This way I know that both of the words are anagrams.

Comment: Why don't you just have d1 = {'star': {'a': 1, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1}}?  What's the purpose of the inner dictionary of just one letter?

Comment: Instead of using a dictionary such as `{{'r': 1}, {'a': 1}, {'t': 1}, {'s': 1}}`, just sort the letters to detect anagram: `sorted('rats') == sorted('star')` ==> `True`

Comment: SORRY! Forgot to add constraints so I just added constraints.

Comment: @GregWhittier THANK YOU. I feel like an idiot. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it and others can use it as well!

Comment: Constraints were part of my interview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seemed to have misread your question, but note that:

```
>>> d1 = {'star': {'r': 1, 'a': 1, 't': 1, 's': 1}}
>>> d2 = {'arts': {'a': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 's': 1}}
>>> d1['star'] == d2['arts']
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two dict at all just store the original word in one dict with an inner dict with the letter frequency  and subtract:

```
d = {'star': {'r': 1, 'a': 1, 't': 1, 's': 1}}

word = "rats"


def checker(d, w1, w2):
    wrd = d[w1]
    for ch in w2:
        if ch not in wrd or wrd[ch] < 1:
            return False
        wrd[ch] -= 1
    return True


print(checker(d, "star",word))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just sorting the string?

```
>>> sorted("star") == sorted("rats")
True
```